# Format the data (ticks) of the x and y axes in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, ticker

I have to process some data for a search in the range of units between nano and micro. I would then like to format them on the graph so that they are all shown on the micro base (10^-6). However, the code I managed to build only shows the first values of the positions corresponding to the array I create '' 'np.arange (6)' '', and not the total range of the data. For example, on the x-axis we have the time, which should go from -0.7725 to 0.42225, but only the first 6 time values appear. Therefore, no curve appears, because for the initial values, Energy is zero.

```
y_num = E*1e+6
x_num = t*1e+6
fmt = lambda x: "{:.4f}".format(x)

plt.plot(t,E)
plt.xlabel('Tempo(µs)')
plt.ylabel('Energia Acumulada (µJ)')
plt.title('Gráfico E X t')
plt.tight_layout()

plt.xticks(np.arange(6), [fmt(n) for n in x_num], rotation = 90)
plt.yticks(np.arange(6), [fmt(n) for n in y_num])
```

[image obtained with the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpWCU.jpg)

Comment: you sure `y_num = E * 10e+6` is correct? Should'nt it be `y_num = E * 1e-6`?

Comment: The corrrect is 1e^+6 rather 10e^+6 cause the data is given around 1e^-6(micro)! But the problem I asked persists, cause that only changes the decimal place. However, thank you! I corrected the error.

Comment: It's hard to help without actual numbers to reproduce the behaviour

Comment: If you could help me I would send you the data and the full code I made.

Comment: Can you change `6` to `len(x_num)` or `len(y_num)` and see if that corrects your issue? I am also having trouble understanding without knowing the data stored in E and t

Comment: I'll try it James Carter! The problem with showing the data in E and t is dueing the extension of it, cause is very large. But I'll try do post the full code here and one filé that i have used.

Comment: Oh, if they're very large then I assume you don't want a tick mark for every data point, which is how I interpreted your question originally. I don't understand how you want the xtick marks, for example.

Comment: @JamesCarter I just want the x and y axis to show the time intervals multiplied by 10 ^ + 6 ... but I managed to do this now after this conversation. I was confusing something that was very simple. Thank you!